# Where to download and how to install current version of Slackware?

Tags: linux-kernel, download, slackware

I'm interested in Slackware. I've read on distrowatch, that Slackware is rolling distro and I'm looking for .iso to download. Which kernel is included by default? Thanks!

Comment: Slackware is at http://www.slackware.com/, which includes both downloads and documentation.

Comment: I can see only 14.2 iso. Is this a correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Start at http://www.slackware.com/getslack/
current kernel is 5.4.6
(https://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware-current/kernels/VERSIONS.TXT)

Comment: The question asks “Where to download …?” and “I'm looking for .iso to download.”  So, while not ideal, a URL ***is*** an essential part of the answer.